# rsync over ssh questions - creating directories on remote host if they don't exist

Tags: ssh, rsync

I want to use rsync to backup some files over ssh which I have managed to get working fine using:

```
rsync --delete -avze ssh /home/malachi/www/site/ malachi@remote-host:~/backups/daily/sites/site/
```

How would I create the sites/site/ directory on the remote-host if it does not already exist?

Would it be best to put the below before running the above command?

```
ssh -l malachi remote-host mkdir -p ~/backups/daily/sites/site/
```

Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the [`mkdir`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/umkdir.htm) command and building a script to handle the backup process

Answer (score 3):

If it is just one level up, rsync will create the directory. Would your command work if you rsync'd the `site` folder rather than the contents? That is:

```
rsync --delete -avze ssh /home/malachi/www/site \ 
malachi@remote-host:~/backups/daily/sites
```

This way, rsync should create the `sites` folder on the remote host as it is just one level up from the `site` folder that you want to copy. Note that this requires the `--recursive` switch, which is implicit with `-a` in your command. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/rsync-how-can-i-configure-it-to-create-target-directory-on-server/5594398#5594398) for details.

There are [wonderfully complicated ways](http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/122048-rsync-creating-dirs-remote-server.html) of doing this if you need to create multiple levels of parent directories.